# Upload google docs with coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, google-docs, cfc

I've built a forum-like app in ColdFusion and I want to add a feature with which the users can upload files to Google Docs using their Google accounts and then other users can edit those files.

I've been using this CFC: http://cfgoogle.riaforge.org/ to retrieve Google Docs, but the upload function is currently missing. I need the upload function for the first upload of the file and then for the second part of editing it. I hope that it makes sense.

That's what I'm asking help for. I'm not that experienced with cffunctions and I was wondering if someone could give me a hand with it.

This is what I have so far:

```
<cffunction name="upload" access="public" returnType="any" hint="I upload the document." output="false">
<cfargument name="myFile" type="string" required="true" hint="file to upload.">

<cfset var result = "">
<cfset var service = variables.docservice>

<cfset theUrl = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full HTTP/1.1">

<cfhttp url="#theURL#" method="post" result="result">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="GoogleLogin auth=#getAuth(service)#">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Length" value="81047">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/msword">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Slug" value="#myFile#">
</cfhttp>

<cfreturn result.filecontent>

</cffunction>
```

But I get the following error when I output the result:
'Invalid request URI'

If someone could help me out with this one (even just show me the way), it would be mostly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to expand `cfgoogle` CFC with `upload` method using [Protocol Guide](http://code.google.com/intl/uk/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UploadingDocs) for uploading.